Difference in hibernate behaviour for maven and gradle JavaFX project
I've been trying to integrate hibernate with my JavaFX Maven project. It was working fine with Hibernate community package, Jakarta and xerial. I have also placed persistence.xml file in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml.
Also I tried to create another project with gradle and Done the ditto of this maven project but it was causing error No Persistence provider for EntityManager named demo. For gradle javafx project the persistence.xml was on the same location as in maven project
pom.xml for your reference
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.46.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-community-dialects</artifactId>
      <version>6.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

persistence.xml for reference
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="demo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:ms.db"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>

            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

My build.gradle from another project is
javafx {
  version = '17.0.6'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects
  implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.6.0.Final'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api
  implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.2.0'

  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
  implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.46.1.0'

  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}


While the spellings are also correct for the persistence unit.
I have tried to sourceSets from build.gradle where it showed error regarding duplicate where I came to conclusion that all the resource files were included. I have also downgraded some versions it's does work. How to resolve this difference in behaviour between maven and gradle? I have seen some use hibernate.cfg.xml which is the best one to go with persistence or hibernate xml file?

This is not a direct answer to your question, so please just ignore it, if the approach is not something you want to use.
Recommendation
What you are doing is trying to use a local embedded database technology with JavaFX.  For me (and this will be different for others), it is better to do that with the following approach:

Use a higher level DB API than Hibernate (e.g. Spring Data).
Use a native Java embedded DB rather than SQLLite (e.g. H2).

Notes
Under the covers it is still a Maven project using Hibernate to access an embedded database, but the Maven dependencies and database configuration tasks are all handled by the Spring Boot Data starter dependency and Spring Boot's auto-configuration from the input application.yaml config and annotation driven configuration in your app.  So you don't need to define things like the persistence.xml, separate hibernate properties files, write boilerplate DAO code, provide a hibernate.cfg.xml, etc.
The drawback is that you have added a couple of layers of abstraction on top of your app, and that can bring further confusion, learning and complexity.  But, IMO, if you are going to invest the time into learning JPA development with a JavaFX API, then you may as well let Spring do some of the work and also learn some of Spring.  Just take it a step at a time and focus on the things you need to learn at the moment to solve each issue you come across rather than trying to learn "all" of Spring.
Using an embedded DB like this is a specific (and valid) model for a client app.  However many client apps (e.g. almost all HTML based web apps, and many stand-alone apps like JavaFX apps or Mobile native apps), do not use an embedded database but instead have the client communicate with a shared web server (often using REST APIs) with the database integration on the server side rather than client.  So consider if your application is actually following an appropriate architectural model for your purposes.
Example
Anyway, here is an example project, in case this approach is something you are interested in.
This examples uses:

Code and concepts from:

Baeldung tutorials.


Info on integrating Spring and JavaFX from:

Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)



pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FXSpringData</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FXSpringData</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

src/main/resources/application.yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    # use this url for a file db named demo stored in the user home dir.
    # url: jdbc:h2:file:~/demo
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
  h2:
    # console is at: http://localhost:8080/h2-console, after app loaded
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: false

src/main/resources/data.sql
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (1, 'USA');
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (2, 'France');
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Brazil');
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Italy');
INSERT INTO countries (id, name) VALUES (5, 'Canada');

src/main/java/org/esample/fxspringdata/SpringApp.java
package org.example.fxspringdata;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FXApp {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
    }   
}

src/main/java/org/esample/fxspringdata/FXApp.java
package org.example.fxspringdata;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.example.fxspringdata.dao.CountryRepository;
import org.example.fxspringdata.model.Country;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class FXApp extends Application {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class);
        springContext
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBeanProperties(
                        this,
                        AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE,
                        true
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<Country> countriesListView = new ListView<>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        countryRepository.findAll()
                )
        );
        countriesListView.setCellFactory(_ -> new CountryListCell());
        countriesListView.setPrefSize(100, 100);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10,
                new Label("Countries from DB"),
                countriesListView
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

src/main/java/org/esample/fxspringdata/CountryListCell.java
package org.example.fxspringdata;

import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import org.example.fxspringdata.model.Country;

public final class CountryListCell extends ListCell<Country> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Country item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            return;
        }

        setText(item.getName());
    }
}

src/main/java/org/esample/fxspringdata/model/Country.java
package org.example.fxspringdata.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Objects;

@Table(name = "countries")
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        Country country = (Country) o;
        return id == country.id && name.equals(country.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country{" +
          "id=" + id +
          ", name='" + name + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
}

src/main/java/org/esample/fxspringdata/dao/CountryRepository.java
package org.example.fxspringdata.dao;

import org.example.fxspringdata.model.Country;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {}

Execution
I use Idea, configuring the project to execute as a non-modular project (no module-info.java defined), the JavaFX SDK matching the version defined in Maven downloaded separately so that the module path and JavaFX runtime components can be easily configured.

The key part being the VM arguments (NOT program arguments):
--module-path <pathtojavafx>/javafx-sdk-22.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls

Replacing <pathtojavafx> with the location of the JavaFX SDK on your machine.
What the App Does
Once run, the app will:

Start up Spring/Hibernate/H2 embedded DB.
Initialize the database with a schema derived from the entities (creating the required Country table).
Insert the provided seed data into the database.
Read the data using Spring Data (which in turn uses Hibernate to access the database via the H2 JDBC driver using a Hikari connection pool).
Display the country list in a JavaFX list view.


